# Compress Raster in ArcMap without generating a new File

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, raster-conversion, compression

I have several uncompressed rasters (FGDBR format) stored in a File-GDB. Now I want to compress this data. The only way I know is to use the "Copy Raster" tool but this will generate a new raster with a new name.

**Is there a way how I can compress this files with LZ77 compression without generating new rasters with new names?**

Comment: @Hornbydd I think you should write that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no, you cannot compress in situ. You could create a model that creates a compressed version, deletes old version and then renames the compressed version so it "appears" to compress in situ. Exposing the inputs as parameters would allow you to develop the model into a tool so it looks and behaves like any other geo-processing tool. You could equally write this as python script and expose it as a script tool that could be combined into a large model.

[image: Model]

*Note I copy the temporary raster again rather than simply renaming it as the rename tool has a bug which insists on inserting a `.tif` at the end.*